# LARAVEL Sub Domain Routing Not Executed

Tags: laravel, configuration, routes, subdomain

Hi there i have some stupid mistake in configuring laravel.

First of all, this is my structure of folder

i use shared-hosting service and i place my laravel app, vendor and bootstrap into `lib` folder outside the htdocs (public/public_html) folder

so basically:

`var
public_html
www
lib
-app
-bootstrap
-vendor`

i create two subdomain called `console` for client and `panel` for admin

so i could call the subdomain specific url to access the system

this two subdomain is placed inside the public_html

`public_html
-console
-panel`

Then i move the `public` folder from laravel original into console folder (subdomain) with all the content from public folder (index.php, .htaccess, etc.)

`Console.myDomain.com` is working perfectly.

Now i want to create the admin system from the `panel.myDomain.com` i have created the subdomain and place all assets files (css, js, etc.) and change the routes into:

`Route::group(array('domain' => 'panel.myDomain.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('admin.index');
    });
});`

but the page only showing blank page, (the blank page is shown because i place index.php file without content inside the panel folder)

additional info i have setup the `bootstrap/paths.php` into `'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html/console'`

and is it require to change?

what proper way to make the `panel.myDomain.com` execute the routes and showing the right blade i have made?

thank you.

Comment: Instead of creating subdomains manually, use wildcard.

Comment: @estshy i just need two subdomains for admin and client panel only. any suggestion to make the `panel.myDomain.com` is executed from `console.myDomain.com` ?

Comment: If you created subdomains for panel and console, then they are two different website. You don't have your laravel instance, I guess. All you can do is http rediect.